# JPA - How to copy and modify it's content of Page object?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have this `Meeting` and `Favorite` models;

```java
public class Meeting implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String meetingTitle;
    private Date meetingStartDate;
    private User host;
}
```

```java
public class MeetingFavorite implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private boolean active = false;
    private Meeting meeting;
    private Date updatedDate;
}
```

And I can successfully fetch `MeetingFavorite` page object like;

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/favorite-meetings", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity searchFavoriteMeetings(
            MeetingFavoriteSpecification search, HttpSession session) {
        Page<MeetingFavorite> page = meetingsService.findFavoriteMeetings(search);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(page);
    }
```

Is it possible to get `Meeting` contents only from `MeetingFavorite` Page w/ it's pagination data?

I tried this and it returns `Meeting` objects. But pagination data is lost.

```java
        Page<MeetingFavorite> page = meetingsService.findFavoriteMeetings(search);
        List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
        page.forEach(entity -> meetings.add(entity.getMeeting()));
        final Page<Meeting> meetingPage = new PageImpl<>(meetings);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(meetingPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the way. Thanks.

```java
        List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
        page.forEach(entity -> meetings.add(entity.getMeeting()));
        Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "updatedDate");
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(search.getOffset() / search.getLimit(), search.getLimit(), sort);
        final Page<Meeting> meetingPage = new PageImpl<Meeting>(meetings, pageable, page.getTotalElements());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(meetingPage);
```